# Is there any way to have all local variables aligned in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

Eclipse has a great feature to allow you to align all your 'fields in columns' meaning that it will turn:

```
int myVar = 2334;
int asdf = 34;
String s = "hello";
```

into

```
int     myVar  = 2334;
int     asdf   = 34;
String  s      = "Hello";
```

This makes the code a lot more readable and I love it. However I can't seem to find a similar setting to make it do that for regular local variables. Anyone know if there is a way? It'd be a shame if there isn't one.

Thanks

Comment: I'd rather call that uglification, because it is misguided (I especially hate to correlate variables and their types across a lot of blank space). For local variables you should declare them where you need them, not at the beginning of a method, so this would be completely useless. Fortunately it doesn't exist AFAIK.

Comment: Well I disagree on it making code uglier or that it's misguided. There are times that you need to declare more than 1 variable in one place and at least for me it makes it a lot easier being able to look at the variables and their types with the least effort. It may just be a preference issue though

Answer (score 4):

If you go in Eclipse's settings, Java -> Code Style -> Formatter, you may edit or create a new profile.

Anyway, in the `Indentation` tab, there is an "Align fields in columns" option that should do what you are looking for.

Comment: fields are not local variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter**

1. Create a **New** Profile
2. check **Align fields in columns**
3. click **ok**
4. **Select all variables** declared.
5. **Ctrl + Shift + F**